# Adding scrollview that is compatable with my layout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make my main layout file scrollable, but whenever I try to change it to a scrollview, I get error messages.  I tried to put a linear view for my widgets and the srollview on the outside but it does not work.  I am wondering if there is a better way to add a scrollview, and one that is compatable with my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.jesse.myapp2.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        tools:textSize="12sp"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
       />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:id="@+id/editText4" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        tools:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:gravity="left"
         android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLines="18"
            tools:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you show how you've tried to put the scrollview?

Comment: I relplaced the Linear layout tag on the top and botton with the scrollview tag and I placed a Iinear layout tag on top of the first editext.

Comment: ScrollView can have only **one direct child**!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `LinearLayout` with `ScrollView` like below.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
...